# Set text column filters to do a full matching check instead of 'Contains'

Tags: datagrid, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

We are using AG Grid React Enterprise with Adaptable.

When we filter on text columns we want to filter for exact matches only but the default seems to be Contains and its annoying for our users to have to remember to change it each time they run a filter and when they forget to do it they end up seeing false positives.

Is there some code we can run so that when the user enters filter text it will force the Grid to do a full match check?

Answer (score 2):

You can set this at design time in SearchOptions where there is a `defaultStringColumnFilter` property.

The default value is 'Contains' which is why your users are seeing that, but you can change this to another Predicate.  So if you want an exact match then set the value to 'Is'.

You can also set the default filters for Number and Date Columns from the current default values of 'Equals' and 'On' respectively.  For example:

```
searchOptions: {
 defaultStringColumnFilter: 'Is',
 defaultNumericColumnFilter: 'GreaterThan',
 defaultDateColumnFilter: 'After'
}
```

See more at Search Options documentation: https://docs.adaptabletools.com/docs/adaptable-options/search-options/